# DELETE .. RETURNING rowid in JOOQ not working

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jooq

I have an oracle database, and am trying to delete a record based on the client number, with the query returning the rowid of the deleted record.  When executing the query, I am getting the following exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field (rowid) is not contained in Row.  If I attempt returning a different field (such as the client_number field itself) instead of rowid, the query works perfectly.

The query I am trying to execute looks like this:

```
ClientDetails clt = CLIENT_DETAILS.as("clt");

ClientDetailsRecord result = context.deleteFrom(clt)
            .where(clt.CLIENT_NUMBER.equal(clientNumber))
            .returning(rowid())
            .fetchOne();
```

Is this a limitation of Jooq, or am I doing this the wrong way?

Comment: The ROWID is a pseudocolumn, i.e. is not actually declared as part of the table. There are also situations where two rows can have the same ROWID. Without knowing what you intend to use it for subsequently its hard to say if it is any use to you. Take a look at https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:53140678334596 for some ROWID considerations.

Comment: @BriteSponge Despite ROWID being a pseudocolumn, JOOQ still allows me to retrieve it via a select query.  Unfortunately, despite it not being 100% safe if used without the primary key, I must still use the rowid, and cannot opt for other workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known (and unfortunate) limitation of jOOQ 3.x, which can only return declared columns of your table `CLIENT_DETAILS`, no "system" columns like `ROWID` or any expressions for that matter. The relevant feature request to rectify this is: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5622

You could work around this limitation by creating your own `CLIENT_DETAILS` table which includes a "synthetic" `ROWID` column, e.g. by:

- Extending the [`CustomTable` type](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts/)
- Extending the code generator by adding the `ROWID` column to your `CLIENT_DETAILS` table (beware that this can have undesired side-effects, e.g. when calling `UpdatableRecord.store()`)

Comment: I have tried extending the JavaGenerator so that whenever the CLIENT_DETAILS table is generated, I would add the ROWID column.  My plan was to override the generateTable(SchemaDefinition, TableDefinition) method, and add a ROWID column to the columns inside the table definition - something which I failed to do since table definition does not have a columns setter.

Comment: What do you mean by "columns setter"? There are various ways to implement this, e.g. you could call the super method, and then add one more column to the generated output...